# Simplification of multiplying fractions

Tags: fractions

*Simplify $(1+\frac{1}{20\times22})(2+\frac{2}{21\times23})(2+\frac{2}{22\times24})(2+\frac{2}{23\times25})(13+\frac{13}{24\times26})$*

I noticed the denominator of the five fractions are all in the form of:$$\frac{...}{(n-1)(n+1)}$$
Which can be simplified to:$$\frac{...}{n^2-1}$$

I futher attempted to move the integral part into the fraction, but it just got more complicated. How should I start from there?

Comment: $k+\frac{k}{(n-1)(n+1)}=k\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m+\frac{m}{(n-1)(n+1)}=m\times(1+\frac{1}{(n-1)(n+1)})=m\times (\frac{n^2-1+1}{(n-1)(n+1)})=m\times\frac{n^2}{(n-1)(n+1)}$$

$$(1+\frac{1}{20\times22})(2+\frac{2}{21\times23})(2+\frac{2}{22\times24})(2+\frac{2}{23\times25})(13+\frac{13}{24\times26})=\frac{21^2}{20\times 22}\times 2\times \frac{22^2}{21\times 23}\times 2\times\frac{23^2}{22\times 24}\times 2\times \frac{24^2}{23\times 25}\times 13 \times \frac{25^2}{24\times 26}=105$$